# Не понимаю как работает этот примитивный код

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SPACE ' ' 

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    ch = getchar(); 


   while (ch != '\n')
    {
        if (ch == SPACE)
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }

        else 
        {
            putchar(ch+1);
        }

        ch = getchar();    
    } 

    putchar(ch); 
}
```

---

Данные на вход: 
One Two

Результат:
Pof Uxp

---

Вопрос: Я не понимаю, почему получилось то, что получилось. Как оно запомнило целую строку, и затем вывела каждый символ на ch+1. Будь это массив, я бы смог такое провернуть с помощью циклов. Однако, это не массив. И переменная "ch" получит от моей введенной строки только лишь первый символ.

Цикл должен был вывести что-то типа:
Pqr Stu

Т.к. значение "ch" = "O", и дальше оно увеличивается на 1 пока не достигнет конца строки.

О назначении последних: ch = getchar(); putchar(ch); могу лишь догадываться.

Comment: *Однако, это не массив.* -- в том смысле, что вам нужно от массива -- это вполне себе массив.

Comment: @D-side, Ну, чтобы строка сохранилась, мне нужно создать массив: char example[n], и только после, я могу уместить в неё строку, так?! А в   данном случае, у меня всего лишь переменная типа char. Она может хранить 1 символ. Надеюсь я ничего не напутал.

Comment: А зачем вам **хранить** весь массив? Вам достаточно его один раз по порядку обойти. Реально вам нужен только **перечислитель**, поддерживающий операции "есть ли следующий" и "получить следующий".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В цикле `while` прочитываются все введенные символы пользователем (символ за символом, то есть посимвольно), пока тот не нажмет клавишу Enter, которой соответствует символ новой строки '\n', помещенной в буфер ввода.

```
ch = getchar(); 

while (ch != '\n')
{
    // ...
    ch = getchar();    
}
```

Итак, будет прочитана строка `"One Two\n"`.

Если текущий прочитанный символ этой строки является пробелом, то он без изменения выводится на консоль.

```
if (ch == SPACE)
{
    putchar(ch);
}
```

Если текущий прочитанный символ этой строки не является пробелом, то выводится символ, который по таблице символов следует за текущим символом, то есть символ, код которого на единицу больше кода текущего прочитанного символа.

```
else 
{
    putchar(ch+1);
}
```

Например, если был введен символ `'O'`, то следующим символом, код которого на единицу больше данного символа в таблице ASCII будет символ `'P'`. И так происходит для каждого введенного непробельного символа.

То есть имеет место следующий процесс. На уровне операционной системы, когда в коде программы встретилась какая-либо команда чтения данных, то в буфер ввода операционной системы вводится вся последовательность символов, пока не встретится символ новой строки. То есть ваша программа не будет работать, пока вы не нажмете клавишу Enter после введенных символов. В этот момент управление имеет операционная система. Как только была нажата клавиша Enter, то управление передается вашей программе, которая последовательно считывает символы из внутреннего буфера операционной системы.

Comment: не понимаю. Что именно двигает процесс к следующему символу в строке, чтобы затем применить к нему ch+1?! Почему ch = getchar(),  следующий после блока ELSE не просит меня опять ввести данные, после первого прогона цикла?! Откуда "оно" знает, что есть 1,2,3... символ?! Я ведь не ввел данные в массив. Сохранился только первый символ в ch. Вы упомянули про буфер, строка хранится там?! Если да, то у меня еще больше вопросов... Я думал, что для любой информации нужно резервировать место с соот-им типом данных, и только после, её можно туда уместить... а тут буфер какой-то... ухх

Comment: @NotSure То, что вы ввели, набрав последовательность символов и нажав клавишу Enter, помещается системой в ее буфер. И вызовы функции getchar последовательно считывают символы из этого буфера в цикле.

Comment: Поразмыслил тут над написанным, кое что почитал в инете, почти понял. Не понял только одно: почему getchar() который в теле цикла читает последовательно символы из буфера?! В смысле: Вне цикла, он запрашивал ввод с клавиатуры т.е вёл себя как scanf (разве что данные закидывал в буфер, а не в переменную), но в теле цикла изменил поведение, и стал отвечать совсем за другое. По сути, достает откуда-то (из буфера в данном случае) данные и принтует их т.е. почти что putchar() или типа того... вот что понять не могу. Или так и задумано было?!

Comment: @NotSure При первом вызове getchar в буфере ввода ничего нет. Поэтому система оживает ввода пользователя. Она передает управление функции getchar, когда пользователь нажмет клавишу Enter.